Definition of stationary subgame perfect Nash Equilibrium in a repeated game
Consider a standard $n$-players infinitely-repeated  game with  pure strategies. Let $\sigma_i$ be the strategy of player $i$. In particular, $\sigma_i$ maps each history $h_t$ to a pure action $a_t$ in each period $t$.
I understand the notion of stationarity for Markov subgame perfect Nash equilibrium. To put it simply, let me denote histories by sequences of capital letters:
(1) Under Markovianity, $\sigma_i(A,B,C)=\sigma_i(D,E,C)$ for each player $i$ (same history length).
(2) Under stationarity+Markovianity, $\sigma_i(A,B,C)=\sigma_i(F,G,H,I,C)$ for each player $i$ (potentially different history length).
Without restricting to Markovian strategies, what is the definition of stationary subgame perfect Nash equilibrium? I cannot find the analogue  of (2) without Markovianity.
