"Repeated games have the additional property that every history gives rise to an identical continuation game."
I am reading Mailath and Samuelson (2006), and I struggle to understand the sentence they have at p.191 on infinitely-repeated games: "Repeated games have the additional property that every history gives rise to an
identical continuation game."
Can you explain to me what this means? Is it somehow suggesting that history does not matter? I confuse this with the fact that strategies are history-dependent.

This only seems to be true for infinitely repeated games, so perhaps add this context.


Is it somehow suggesting that history does not matter?

It is suggesting that history may not matter. They are just saying that if, in a given round $t$, all players are willing to take the preceeding payoffs but otherwise forget what happened before, then the repated game starting in round $t$ is identical to the game starting in round $0$, except for the now fixed payoffs earned before round $t$.
The game and the strategies you can follow are identical, even if you chose not to follow some strategy in it because of something that happened before round $t$, meaning you had a history dependent strategy. You also had the option not to follow this strategy in round $0$, whether you did or did not do so is not relevant.

Thanks, can you take a look also at my other question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/58775/definition-of-stationary-subgame-perfect-nash-equilibrium-in-a-repeated-game

Unfortunately I am not familiar with the concepts you talk about it in that one.
